# Php Year Month Calculation

Tags: php, mysql

Friends, I need to get data from year='2015' and month='8' using from & to. But I got only empty results. Please help me out. Here is my Query.

```
SELECT *
FROM me_fees
WHERE year= '2015' 
&& month = '8' 
&& register_no= '9' 
&& year BETWEEN '2015' AND '2015' 
&& month BETWEEN '6' AND '12'
```

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: Your last 2 conditions are useless

Comment: Why are you using between year if they are the same? is it like dynamically generated or you are writing it intentionally ?

Comment: no  register_no      fid   year  month  re_no  amount

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: You also need to replace `&&` with `AND`.

Comment: Not necessarily @vdwijngaert. For MySQL they both work

Comment: You're absolutely right, but it is to be avoided nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM me_fees
WHERE year= '2015' &&
month = '8' && register_no= '9' && year
BETWEEN '2015'
AND '2015' &&
month BETWEEN '6'
AND '12'
```

That query uses Mysql reserved words which need to be escaped, like `month` and `year` if they are your field names escape them with back tick like

```
`month`
```

Then your last 2 conditions are useless. An equivalent but correct query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM me_fees
WHERE `year`= 2015 AND `month`= 8 AND register_no= 9
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1. I was thinking the exact same about the last 2 conditions.